# Implementing a Persistent Data Queue for guaranteed cloud sync on Android

Tags: android, rest, http, bigdata

I'm developing a real time data collection application of Android.
Currently I produce ~1.2 KB of data  each second, and i need to upload them each second to a remote server through a REST API.

Problem is that this data is critical and I can't tolerate any loss. So I need to cache them on disk and upload the data to remote server. After a confirmed delivery of each data, it can be deleted from the cache, otherwise cache must be preserved until it gets uploaded successfully, even after a device reboot.

What are the the best approached to solve this problem in your point of views?
What are the tools/frameworks/libraries that might be helpful in creating the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with Square Tape (http://square.github.io/tape/) it guarantees that data will be written to disk no matter what. You can handle then your own logic of syncing it and re-queueing in case of a failure.

Comment: Tape seems to be good for that purpose, then what about data upload, Square also has okHttp and Retrofit frameworks, but i haven't yet decided what and how to use them.

Comment: Once in a while, when you decide to upload your data (depends on your logic) just pop out the data or some of it and start uploading it. Prepare yourself for failed items - then just return them to queue and try later. You should be good and data should be safe.

Comment: Yes that sounds good enough :) Thanks @Marky will now give a chance to Tape then..

Comment: @ MarkySmarky I was looking at Tape, but couldn't find any documentation on it. Do you know any place I can find a proper documentation or implementation guide.?

Comment: You have a sample app here (https://github.com/square/tape/tree/master/tape-sample) and some here (https://github.com/square/tape)

Comment: I also found another tool for the same purpose, https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue